# How to determine the top element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a complex structure of many nested, absolutely positioned elements.

These elements may or may not have their z-index set.

They also may or may not have the same parent element.

I am wondering what is the best / simplest way to return which element is on 'top'.  Something like the following...

> $(".panel").topMost()

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin is there ..`topZindex`

```
$.topZIndex("div");
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the element with highest z-index:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array = [];
    $("*").each(function() {
        array.push($(this).css("z-index"));
    });
    var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, array);
    console.log(highest);
});
```

Comment: The trouble is some of the time there won't be a z-index value set.  So you can't use css("z-index").  In those situations it is actually the position of the element in the DOM relative to the other elements that determines whether it is on top

Comment: @user1031947 Can you create a fiddle to demonstrate your situation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var z = [];
$('.panel').each(function(i, el) {
  var $panel = $(el),
      zindex = $panel.css('z-index');
  z[zindex] = $panel;
});

var topMost = z.slice(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you don't specify `z-index` to absolute elems then `last of the element will be on top of other elems`, means `last element will have a greater highest default z-index calculated by browser` itself.

### Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLB2W/

```
var array = [];
$("*").each(function () {
   if ($(this).css('position') == 'absolute') {
       array.push($(this).css("position")+'<--pos & class -->'+$(this).attr('class'));
    }
});

 console.log(array[array.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with Modal dialog while displaying jQuery UI datepicker and using event parameters to figure out the clicked icon. Modal dialog overlay was preventing the new datepicker from showing on top of the modal dialog. 
 
 
The best solution worked in three browsers (IE, Firefox, and Chrome) is:

```
     function topZIndex(target, selector) {
          var objs = $(target).parents(selector + '[z-index > 0]');
          var a1 = -1;
          $.each(objs, function (index, z1) {a1=(z1.style.zIndex > a1)? z1.style.zIndex : a1; });
          return a1;
      };
```

using event parameters as follows:

```
    var zIndex = topZIndex(event.currentTarget, 'div')+1;
```

or

```
    var zIndex = topZIndex(event.currentTarget, '*')+1;
```

Both combinations will generate same result, however it is more efficient to be specific by specifying 'div' instead of '*'
Then assuming my date picker id is datepickerpanel to set the new zIndex for datepicker

```
    $('#datepickerpanel').css('z-index', zIndex);
```

This solution provides proper z-index value to place the new object on top of modal dialog.